# Iterating through nested hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I have a json file:

```
{
"public_holidays": [
{
"date": "2013/1/1",
"name": "New Years Day" 
},
{
"date": "2013/1/21",
"name": "Luther King Day"
},
{
"date": "2013/5/27",
"name": "Memorial Day"
}
]
}
```

My goal is try to capture all of the dates in this file. I am able to get the date on a specific index, but not all the dates at once. Here is what I have:

```
@file = File.read('public_holidays.json')

def json_file
  holiday_dates = JSON.parse(@file)
  holiday_dates.each do |key, value|
    puts value[0]['date']
  end
end
```

This results in 2013/1/1, but I need all the dates, not just one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Iterate over the public holidays.

Comment: In this particular example, you could forget it's JSON and just pull the dates from the string with a regex: `@file.scan(/\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/) #=> ["2013/1/1", "2013/1/21", "2013/5/27"]`. I'm not advocating this; I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: Your JSON example is invalid. Please fix it so we can tell what its structure is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will only grab the first element in the `"public_holidays"` array.

Try something like this:

```
holiday_dates = JSON.parse(@file)
dates = holiday_dates['public_holidays'].map { |x| x['date'] }
```

Comment: perfect. this is exactly what i needed, thanks August! I will accept in 6 minutes (still on a time limit...)